# Can't get DataList HTML Table rendered to resize Height property

Tags: html, asp.net

I have a frustrating issue here that I can't seem to solve. I have a ASP.NET DataList which ends up getting rendered as a HTML `<table>` with columns and rows. This DataList is also contained within a HTML `<table>` that has columns and rows.

When the page renders, I have my window resized to 790x500 and my footer runs across the bottom. The overall page looks great. However this DataList is **not** resizing smaller and is containing a height expanding past my footer creating a scroll bar on the main page. I really need that DataList to be around 250px to fit in the window. For testing I'm using 100px just to see if I can get it resized.

I can't get this rendered `<table>` or surrounding elements to resize no matter what I try. I'm using the developer tools and changing the height to 100px on every containing element and nothing seems to shrink up the height. I even tried the sever control's `Height` [property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.webcontrol.height%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and that didn't work either (width property works fine). The DOM is a bit large, but this should show what I have and none of it has worked:

```
<div class="row-fluid">
  <div class="span12" style="height: 100px;">
    <table style="height: 100px;">
      <tbody style="height: 100px;">
         <tr style="height: 100px;">
            <td style="height: 100px;">
              <table style="width: 100%; height: 100px; overflow-x: hidden; overflow-y: scroll;">
                 <tbody style="height: 100px;">
                       <tr style="height: 100px;">
                           <td style="height: 100px;">
     The culprit is here-->   <table id="DataList1" style="width: 670px; height: 100px; border-top-style: inset; border-right-style: inset; border-bottom-style: inset; border-left-style: inset; border-collapse: collapse;" cellspacing="0">
                                   <tbody style="height: 100px;">
```

At this point I use the ruler and the table containing the DataList measures around 372px, much larger than 100px. The DataList seems to be resizing to fit all of the data inside of it, but I can't find *anything* in the DOM remotely 372px as an attribute. Even so everything I tried and I can't get the height to shrink.

What in the world am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well the solution here was to wrap the `DataList` control in a `<DIV>` to control the height, as opposed to manipulating all of the surrounding `<table>` element pieces. This fixed the issue and allowed the height of the control to be set as needed:

```
<div style="height: 190px; overflow-x: hidden; overflow-y: auto;">
    <asp:DataList ID="DataList1" runat="server"
                  Width="670px">
    ...
</div>
```